# how to send request to a server which is without static ip and connected locally to the router?

Tags: networking, router, routing

I have a computer with static broadband connection connected to ethernet of my computer having ip address 192.1.1.10, the computer is internally connected with a router and has a local address 100.10.10.1 . One of the device connected to router acts as a server to process requests and send response. Its address is 100.10.10.12.

Now all the requests coming from external network comes to the static address(192.1.1.10) and i want it to be forwarded to server internally(100.10.10.12), then what should i do?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What address is assigned to the router? Do you have a single public IP address and a number of devices that have private IP addresses? What you say "without static IP", do you mean that you can't assign it a static IP on your LAN for some reason? Or just that it doesn't have a public IP address?

Comment: i have a pc with internet connection(static public ip 192.1.1.10) conected to internet via ethernet, which is also connected to wlan router thus having an wlan ip in local network(inside my home)(it is 100.10.10.1). so my pc has two ips.right? next my local server runs on laptop which is connected to wlan alone and having local ip 100.10.10.12. now if some one sends requests to my pc through internet. it reaches 192.1.1.10 and after getting the request i want the pc to forward the request to my local server and then vice versa for response. how is it possible?

Comment: It depends what operating system your PC is using and what kinds of "request" you're trying to forward. You probably want some kind of proxy.

Comment: In ubuntu 12.04 os, HTTP requests/responses

Comment: Why have you separated your wlan scope from your LAN scope? With this, pc's cannot communicate with eachother, which is your issue. For best practice, you should disable the DHCP on one of the two devices, so that the other device can do DCHP for the whole network. Some routers allow guest WLAN options by giving a different SSID and password.

Comment: @dachana Then you should probably just run some nice HTTP proxy like Squid or Varnish.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a **Port Forwarding** on your router.
A few links to get you started:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT

And probably this one:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPNP

Example:

1. Your router (public IP) *receives* a connection on port 80 (or any other port you configured)
2. Your router knows, that all requests on port 80 should be forwarded to a specific computer in your network (depending on your router you might have the option to choose from either MAC-Adress, static IP or computer Name)
3. Your router will forward that connection request to the pc you configured.

This setting is usually accessible via the web-interface of your router

To configure it you have to know a few things beforehand:

- Internal IP of your server (100.10.10.12)
- Protocol (UDP and/or TCP)
- Port or Portrange (80, 443, 8001-8009, etc.)

**Important!**

You will (most certainly) not be able to test that connection from *within* you network.

To test it from outside you can use this site for example:

http://ping.eu/port-chk/

It will try to connect to a specified port and tell you if it was able to establish a connection.

Comment: u have to note that the router does not have public IP, only the PC does. It should act as a gateway between the router and the external internet clients.

Comment: one another doubt - in the system you suggested, how does the router handle the responses sent from the server?